# Is there a battery grip for the D3200 with a command dial on it?

Tags: nikon, camera-controls, battery-grip

Are there any battery grips for the D3200 with command dial on it? I ask because the one on my camera is broken. Are there any other alternatives where I can get a sub-command dial?

Answer (score 4):

It's highly doubtful such a grip exists.

Nikon did not design the D3200 to accommodate a grip.

Nikon doesn't offer a grip for the D3200 and other D3xx0 series cameras.

There are no additional contacts in the D3200 battery well to allow communication between controls on a grip and the camera. Most DSLRs that may be used with a manufacturer's battery grip have multiple contacts in the battery well to connect the various controls of the grip to the camera. A few have a socket in the floor plate of the camera that allows the same thing.

Even the shutter button on third party grips must be connected via the D3200's wired cable release port. For this reason no third party grip I can find for the D3200 has *any* controls other than the shutter button.